# How to get value from python dataframe based on column index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big dataframe from which I'm only selecting p_values. However, all p_values have the same column names. So what I've done is the following first:

```
p_value_df = df.filter(regex='p_value')

p_value_df.columns = ['p_value1', 'p_value2', 'p_value3', 'p_value4', 'p_value5']
```

#### Here's the data:

```
{'p_value1': {0: '<0.001', 55: '0.092', 4: '0.003', 1: '0.005', 2: '0.212', 3: '0.012', 9: '0.056', 12: '<0.001', 8: '<0.001', 5: '<0.001', 11: '0.058', 7: '<0.001', 10: '<0.001', 6: '<0.001', 39: '<0.001', 36: '<0.001', 35: '<0.001', 37: '<0.001', 38: '<0.001', 40: '<0.001', 41: '<0.001', 42: '<0.001', 44: '<0.001', 43: '<0.001', 22: '<0.001', 33: '<0.001', 24: '<0.001', 23: '<0.001', 16: '<0.001', 19: '<0.001', 26: '<0.001', 28: '<0.001', 18: '<0.001', 14: '<0.001', 30: '<0.001', 13: '<0.001', 17: '<0.001', 34: '<0.001', 29: '<0.001', 15: '<0.001', 25: '<0.001', 32: '<0.001', 27: '<0.001', 31: '<0.001', 20: '<0.001', 21: '<0.001', 47: '0.366', 46: '0.202', 51: '0.033', 49: '<0.001', 50: '<0.001', 52: '0.028', 54: '0.019', 48: '<0.001', 53: '0.008', 45: '0.340', 56: '0.102', 57: '0.012', 58: '0.092', 59: '0.465', 60: '0.004', 61: '0.079', 62: '0.407', 63: '0.220', 64: '0.058', 65: '0.061', 66: '0.047', 67: '0.047', 68: '0.030', 69: '0.025', 70: '<0.001', 71: '0.163'}, 'p_value2': {0: '<0.001', 55: '<0.001', 4: '0.001', 1: '0.119', 2: '0.013', 3: '0.099', 9: '<0.001', 12: '<0.001', 8: '<0.001', 5: '<0.001', 11: '0.055', 7: '<0.001', 10: '<0.001', 6: '<0.001', 39: '<0.001', 36: '<0.001', 35: '<0.001', 37: '<0.001', 38: '<0.001', 40: '<0.001', 41: '<0.001', 42: '<0.001', 44: '<0.001', 43: '<0.001', 22: '<0.001', 33: '<0.001', 24: '<0.001', 23: '<0.001', 16: '<0.001', 19: '<0.001', 26: '<0.001', 28: '<0.001', 18: '<0.001', 14: '<0.001', 30: '<0.001', 13: '<0.001', 17: '<0.001', 34: '<0.001', 29: '<0.001', 15: '<0.001', 25: '<0.001', 32: '<0.001', 27: '<0.001', 31: '<0.001', 20: '<0.001', 21: '<0.001', 47: '0.136', 46: '0.097', 51: '0.202', 49: '0.024', 50: '0.118', 52: '0.877', 54: '<0.001', 48: '0.052', 53: '0.711', 45: '0.011', 56: '0.002', 57: '0.136', 58: '0.015', 59: '0.072', 60: '0.079', 61: '0.004', 62: '0.005', 63: '0.393', 64: '<0.001', 65: '<0.001', 66: '0.008', 67: '0.123', 68: '0.186', 69: '0.005', 70: '<0.001', 71: '<0.001'}, 'p_value3': {0: '<0.001', 55: '0.123', 4: '0.426', 1: '0.012', 2: '0.451', 3: '0.031', 9: '<0.001', 12: '<0.001', 8: '<0.001', 5: '<0.001', 11: '0.082', 7: '<0.001', 10: '<0.001', 6: '<0.001', 39: '<0.001', 36: '<0.001', 35: '<0.001', 37: '0.017', 38: '<0.001', 40: '<0.001', 41: '<0.001', 42: '<0.001', 44: '<0.001', 43: '<0.001', 22: '<0.001', 33: '<0.001', 24: '<0.001', 23: '<0.001', 16: '<0.001', 19: '<0.001', 26: '<0.001', 28: '<0.001', 18: '<0.001', 14: '<0.001', 30: '<0.001', 13: '<0.001', 17: '<0.001', 34: '<0.001', 29: '<0.001', 15: '<0.001', 25: '<0.001', 32: '<0.001', 27: '<0.001', 31: '<0.001', 20: '<0.001', 21: '<0.001', 47: '0.512', 46: '0.304', 51: '<0.001', 49: '0.072', 50: '0.987', 52: '0.304', 54: '<0.001', 48: '0.178', 53: '0.001', 45: '<0.001', 56: '<0.001', 57: '<0.001', 58: '<0.001', 59: '<0.001', 60: '<0.001', 61: '<0.001', 62: '<0.001', 63: '<0.001', 64: '<0.001', 65: '<0.001', 66: '<0.001', 67: '<0.001', 68: '<0.001', 69: '<0.001', 70: '<0.001', 71: '<0.001'}, 'p_value4': {0: '0.004', 55: '<0.001', 4: '<0.001', 1: '<0.001', 2: '0.002', 3: '0.507', 9: '<0.001', 12: '0.010', 8: '<0.001', 5: '<0.001', 11: '0.292', 7: '<0.001', 10: '<0.001', 6: '<0.001', 39: '<0.001', 36: '<0.001', 35: '<0.001', 37: '<0.001', 38: '<0.001', 40: '<0.001', 41: '<0.001', 42: '<0.001', 44: '<0.001', 43: '<0.001', 22: '<0.001', 33: '<0.001', 24: '<0.001', 23: '<0.001', 16: '<0.001', 19: '<0.001', 26: '<0.001', 28: '<0.001', 18: '<0.001', 14: '<0.001', 30: '<0.001', 13: '<0.001', 17: '<0.001', 34: '<0.001', 29: '<0.001', 15: '<0.001', 25: '<0.001', 32: '<0.001', 27: '<0.001', 31: '<0.001', 20: '<0.001', 21: '<0.001', 47: '0.627', 46: '<0.001', 51: '0.957', 49: '<0.001', 50: '<0.001', 52: '<0.001', 54: '<0.001', 48: '<0.001', 53: '0.695', 45: '<0.001', 56: '<0.001', 57: '<0.001', 58: '<0.001', 59: '<0.001', 60: '<0.001', 61: '<0.001', 62: '<0.001', 63: '<0.001', 64: '<0.001', 65: '<0.001', 66: '<0.001', 67: '<0.001', 68: '<0.001', 69: '<0.001', 70: '<0.001', 71: '<0.001'}, 'p_value5': {0: '<0.001', 55: '<0.001', 4: '<0.001', 1: '0.019', 2: '<0.001', 3: '<0.001', 9: '<0.001', 12: '0.284', 8: '<0.001', 5: '<0.001', 11: '<0.001', 7: '<0.001', 10: '<0.001', 6: '<0.001', 39: '<0.001', 36: '<0.001', 35: '<0.001', 37: '0.111', 38: '<0.001', 40: '<0.001', 41: '<0.001', 42: '<0.001', 44: '<0.001', 43: '<0.001', 22: '<0.001', 33: '<0.001', 24: '<0.001', 23: '<0.001', 16: '<0.001', 19: '<0.001', 26: '<0.001', 28: '<0.001', 18: '<0.001', 14: '<0.001', 30: '<0.001', 13: '<0.001', 17: '<0.001', 34: '<0.001', 29: '<0.001', 15: '<0.001', 25: '<0.001', 32: '<0.001', 27: '<0.001', 31: '<0.001', 20: '<0.001', 21: '<0.001', 47: '0.032', 46: '<0.001', 51: '0.807', 49: '0.239', 50: '0.496', 52: '0.393', 54: '<0.001', 48: '0.092', 53: '0.259', 45: '<0.001', 56: '<0.001', 57: '0.005', 58: '<0.001', 59: '<0.001', 60: '<0.001', 61: '<0.001', 62: '<0.001', 63: '<0.001', 64: '<0.001', 65: '<0.001', 66: '<0.001', 67: '<0.001', 68: '0.016', 69: '<0.001', 70: '<0.001', 71: '<0.001'}}
```

So, what I want to do is, for row, identify the smallest p_value, and create a column with the smallest p_value like the example below:

```
   p_value1 p_value2 p_value3 p_value4 p_value5   p_value
0    <0.001   <0.001   <0.001    0.004   <0.001   <0.001
55    0.092   <0.001    0.123   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001
4     0.003    0.001    0.426   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001
1     0.005    0.119    0.012   <0.001    0.019   <0.001
2     0.212    0.013    0.451    0.002   <0.001   <0.001
3     0.012    0.099    0.031    0.507   <0.001   <0.001
9     0.056   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001
12   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001    0.010    0.284   <0.001
8    <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001
5    <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001
11    0.058    0.055    0.082    0.292   <0.001   <0.001
7    <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001
10   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001
6    <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001
39   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001
36   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001
35   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001
37   <0.001   <0.001    0.017   <0.001    0.111   <0.001
38   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001
40   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001
41   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001
42   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001
44   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001
43   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001
22   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001
33   0.004     0.002    0.090    0.103    0.003    0.002
24   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001
```

**My attempt**

I thought, perhaps, I could first select the column with the smallest value and then filter is based on that, but it doesn't seem to be working. I keep getting this error:

```
p_value = p_value_df.replace('<','', regex=True).astype(float).idxmin(axis=1)

p_value.apply(lambda x: p_value_df.iloc[:x])

TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on Int64Index with these indexers [p_value1] of type str
```

How can I resolve this so that I can get the results like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to convert your data to same type so as `<0.001` is the smallest. So, something like:

```
df.replace('<0.001', '0.001').astype(float)
```

Then you can take `min` along rows with `min(axis=1)`:

```
min_p = df.replace('<0.001', '0.001').astype(float).min(axis=1)
```

Now you can put back the string `<0.001` with `.where`:

```
# 1e-9 is for floating point precision
df['p_value'] = min_p.where(min_p>0.001 + 1e-9, '<0.001')
```

Output:

```
   p_value1 p_value2 p_value3 p_value4 p_value5 p_value
0    <0.001   <0.001   <0.001    0.004   <0.001  <0.001
55    0.092   <0.001    0.123   <0.001   <0.001  <0.001
4     0.003    0.001    0.426   <0.001   <0.001  <0.001
1     0.005    0.119    0.012   <0.001    0.019  <0.001
2     0.212    0.013    0.451    0.002   <0.001  <0.001
..      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...     ...
67    0.047    0.123   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001  <0.001
68    0.030    0.186   <0.001   <0.001    0.016  <0.001
69    0.025    0.005   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001  <0.001
70   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001  <0.001
71    0.163   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001   <0.001  <0.001

[72 rows x 6 columns]
```

---

**Update** Note that `<0.001` is actually the maximal **string** when compared to other string-typed floats. So we can do:

```
df['p_value'] = np.where(df.eq('<0.001').any(1), '<0.001', df.min(axis=1) )
```

And we would get the same result.

Comment: this produces p_value min with 0.001 after replaced? We still want the actual value of '<0.001'. There could be some value where p_value = 0.001

Comment: Yeah .. this is great. Thanks

Comment: The updated answer is cool. I like this one. Thank you